# Java NPE error (attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabs, android-viewpager

I was trying to implement a ViewPager with my app so I could swipe between 2 tabs, which are supposed to be in 2 different fragments. These two tabs are the ADD tab and a LIST tab. The user fills in information in the ADD tab and it gets displayed in the LIST tab. It worked perfectly fine with a TabHost however now I am trying to use a ViewPager it does not work and Android studio gives me a NPE and my phone says "Unfortunately ... has stopped"

After following a tutorial it said that I should put a ViewPager in my activity_main.xml where previously the UI for the add tab was. I created a new XML layout file(add_fragment) and put the UI from the activity_main into the add_fragment and then put the ViewPager into the activity_main. If I put the UI elements together with the ViewPager, the ViewPager blocks all the Ui elements so you only have a blank background.

The problem is that with my MainActivity.java when I   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) It cannot find the UI elements in the add_fragment and hence returns null but if I put setContentView(R.layout.add_fragment)it cannot find the ViewPager and I receive a NPE as well.

**NPE**

```
    7-07 09:31:47.870    1837-1837/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid parameter app
07-07 09:31:47.870    1837-1837/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
07-07 09:31:47.871  11145-11145/com.mycompany.appointmentmanager D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
07-07 09:31:47.872  11145-11145/com.mycompany.appointmentmanager E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mycompany.appointmentmanager, PID: 11145
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.appointmentmanager/com.mycompany.appointmentmanager.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2329)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:147)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1296)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
            at com.mycompany.appointmentmanager.MainActivity.showDialogOnEditTextClick(MainActivity.java:199)
            at com.mycompany.appointmentmanager.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:77)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2282)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:147)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1296)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
```

**activity_main**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Any help would be HUGELY appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you add more details about the NPE? Like show teh first few lines of the exception.

Comment: Add more details, your code and the exception. Describing a problem does not get solutions.

Comment: I added the error and activity_main